# Whats a succinct way to express 'If an array exists then do'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a more succinct way of expressing the following:

```
if Model.all
  array = Model.all
  array.each do |a|
    a.info
  end
end
```

In my case, `Model.all` is a helper method (`get_all_of_those()`).

In the view, I am displaying data in tables based on the results. `a.info` might be

```
"<div class='row'>#{a.name}</div>"
```

Comment: What is the intention behind `if Model.all`? Check that it is not empty?

Comment: You could do a variable assignment in the if condition: `if models = Model.all.presence` (`.presence` returns the object(s) if it returns true to `.present?`, if not it returns nil)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Model.all` is always truthy and is always an array-like object (Strictly speaking it's ActiveRecord::Relation object in rails 4; an Array in rails 3). You can just do:

```
Model.all.each do |a|
  a.info
end
```

If there are no models, the loop will not be executed even once.

(Note however, that this code doesn't do anything interesting with models, so you need to update your question with: What do you want the final result to be? There is a chance that you are looking for `Model.pluck(:info)`)

Comment: Isn't a bit inefficient, when Model has thousands of rows?

Comment: @Bala - All depends on what is the true purpose of the code. As it is it is very inefficient, as it does not do a thing (unless info is some super-complicated method defined on model which does a lot of stuff, I would name it `info!` then though). If there are many records, then `find_each` is a way to improve memory-usage.

Comment: The OP is asking for a more *succinct*, not a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
  Model.all.find_each do |a|
    a.info
  end
```

Read more about [find_each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If `info` is a field in the database, you could do this more efficiently with

```
array = Model.pluck(:info)
```